# Navigation in semantic environment and reasoning

Tags: knowrob

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello

I want to navigate my robot through doors and other object using reasoning and semantic maps. So I have the map of my environment but the objects are not labelled on that map. So was thinking to use more knowledge about my environment and also to do reasoning about it.

So I found that a using of knowledge base like KnowRob( http://www.ros.org/wiki/knowrob ) to store e.g. semantic environment information (in a so called semantic map) is a good approach. But the wiki is pretty mess so do not know for example how to generate that semantic map from my already exist yaml map ( I could not find that).

Im using inly laser range sensor and no point cloud dates. Any useful help or some examples that can help?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/41301/navigation-in-semantic-environment-and-reasoning/) by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on ROS Answers with karma: 330 on 2012-08-13

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Sorry, the wiki is not necessarily 'a mess' just because there is no tutorial for exactly your use case. All relevant tutorials and more in-depth descriptions are directly linked from the [knowrob wiki page on ros.org](http://www.ros.org/wiki/knowrob).

Effectively using the system and adapting it to your needs won't work without some learning from your side. I'd recommend to go through the basic tutorials and have a closer look at those about methods for [reasoning about objects](http://ias.in.tum.de/kb/wiki/index.php/Reasoning_about_objects) or the [representation of map data](http://ias.in.tum.de/kb/wiki/index.php/Map_data_representation).

Besides, there are quite some [publications](http://ias.cs.tum.edu/people/tenorth/publications) describing different aspects of the system.

---

Originally posted by [moritz](https://answers.ros.org/users/214/moritz/) with karma: 2673 on 2012-08-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on 2012-08-14**:
Ok. But could not find how to use my environment yaml map in knowrob. So how to convert in in OWL??

**Comment by [moritz](https://answers.ros.org/users/214/moritz/) on 2012-08-14**:
There is no direct conversion. Your YAML file does only describe the extension of the map and the conversion from pixel space to metric space. You'll need to create the semantic map yourself because it contains much more information which cannot be extracted automatically from an occupancy grid map.

**Comment by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on 2012-08-14**:
OK. And there is tutorial or example how to create the semantic map from my occupancy grid map?Because I already have that map of the environment. Im using gmapping and the map server. So I want to use that information in knowrob and to create the semantic map from that. Is that possible?

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-08-15**:
As Moritz already said, you will have to do some manual work to construct the map. There is no automatic way right now. There are a lot of examples of semantic maps in the knowrob repository and there are a bunch of publications that teach you the basics which you should understand first.

**Comment by [ctguell](https://answers.ros.org/users/5132/ctguell/) on 2013-09-02**:
@moritz Im trying to detect objects with a kinect , so i can later use this information in the navigation stack of ROS, and wanted to know if this knowrob package can learn from kinect data and if so can it learn with a moving camera?? thanks for the help